# Azure DevOps repository, share pull requests

Tags: .net, git, azure, devops

I have a web application project repository on Azure DevOps (.Net core API linked to a React frontend).
I want to create another repository where i have a totally different user interface design for the same application features. Is there a way to synchronize both repositories and have pull requests created on the first project to be added on the second (new design) repository as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot synchronize repositories **Out of Box** in Azure DevOps. *But, there are many ways to achieve this goal. Here are 2 ways of achieving this:*

1. Have 2 repositories for different UI codes and 1 different repository with common code (shared code). This way, you can make changes and create PRs for Common Code Repo which will be used by the other repos.
2. Make changes in 1 Repo by cloning it and similarly make same changes by cloning the other repo. Now, create 2 different PRs for same code but in respective repos.

*My suggestion is to go for **first** option as it is widely used.* The second option requires much manual work and havok.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Is creating a fork of the initial repository a bad idea?  This way we could make the changes (functionalities) only once and create two PRs (one on the initial repo and one for the new design repo).

Comment: Yes, you can fork it, it is fine, provided you have completely same code in both the repositories and just want to make same changes to both the repositories. But, in this case, there is no point of having two separate repositories. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: There will be changes (mostly on the backend) that we'll replicate on both repositories by creating 2 PRs each time, and changes that will be specific to either repos (main or fork). The point is to simplify the task not to manually replicate code changes on both repositories.

Comment: So, as I mentioned above, pls keep backend (shared code) in separate repository. This way you can make changes using 1 pr in this repo and in pipeline, use all the 3 repos to deploy. I hope I am clear.

Comment: Yes that's clear. In my case it's not obvious separating backend and front since the project was created with the VS .Net Core - React template including Identity for managing authentication. After scaffolding Identity we get these [Identity files](https://static.gunnarpeipman.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/aspnet-core-identity-scaffolded-pages.png) which are views. This means the Identity folder will be on both frontend repositories (to have different UI designs). The problem is that to view changes on these files they have to be run with the backend .Net Core application. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Sure, pls mark the response as answer to help other community members.